# Java, Eclipse and SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, database-connection

I'm pretty new with Java (though I'm experienced with C#).
Anyway I've Googled a lot in the last few hours and I can't understand something.  I'm hoping you can help me with some guidance.

I'd like to use Eclipse with SQL Server and I have no idea how am I doing that.
I've seen some plugin called SQLExplorer but I just can't figure what are the steps to integrate with that.

Regarding:

- What is the best way of doing that?
- Is there any guide or full tutorial?
- Maybe you have some source code example of a connection to SQL?
- Should I use that plugin? How?
- Why is it so difficult to find info about this issue? Isn't eclipse familiar with SQL?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java and databases go together like bread and butter, but the language is just different enough that you might have issues breaking in. There are a number of different levels at which things can be integrated: the traditional query/result API is called JDBC, and all you need to work with any database from Java code is the appropriate JDBC driver. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724) is the official one from Microsoft for SQL Server, and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) is a tutorial about using the JDBC API.

Above that, there are object-relational mapping tools like Hibernate which let you persist Java objects directly onto your database. Hibernate automates a lot of the mapping and lets you work at a high level. Hibernate is an enormous subject; start [here.](http://www.hibernate.org/)

What SQLExplorer, and tools like it, let you do is browse around in a database, exploring the tables and the data in them. It's not something you use with code, but rather interactively to examine the data you're working with.

Here is a JDBC "Hello World," assuming the default database on the local machine, a table named `some_table_name` has a character-valued column in the first position:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
Statement s = con.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM some_table_name");
while (r.next()) {
    System.out.println(r.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: Erm, i installed that driver, checking out that tutorial and also viewed some ytube videos, i cant find something relevant to SQL Server (only for apache/mysql), can u give me an extra guide?

Comment: It's exactly the same, except the connection information (i.e., the name of the class, and the connection string) are appropriate for the driver. See, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=SQL.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms378956(v=sql.90).aspx (under "Creating a connection with the DriverManager class).

Comment: i was viewing this in the past hour and also tried to work with hibernate, im guessing im doing something wrong but can't figure what.. :-(

Comment: I added a "Hello, World" program for you to try. What sort of errors are you seeing?

Comment: im trying to run ur code (as i imported import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
) but the code doesnt compile, this line: "while (r.hasNext()) { " The method hasNext() is undefined for the type ResultSet

Comment: ok fixed, i added try catch, im getting this error: "20/01/2012 17:28:25 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path" at this line: con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);, any idea?

Comment: Take the `;integratedSecurity=true;` off of the connection string.

Comment: now im getting 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.' (and the con object remains null)
im sorry im bugging u with my comments in here, i can stop lol but to tell u the truth im pretty surprised i cant find a decent video tutorial regarding this issue (or hibernate+sql)

Comment: Well, now you need to be reading those web pages I pointed you to -- the "Building the Connection URL" one shows how to specify username/password right under the "Connection Examples" heading.

Comment: i wasted like another hour-or two 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.' cant solve this :(

Comment: Okay at last i managed to do it, i made a simple connection using what u gave me thanks for that, now im trying the hibernate wayyyyy..!

Comment: I'm glad you're making progress!